# Moving partition-by's splits "back by one"

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, enumeration, clojurescript, seq

I'm parsing some Hiccup in CLJS, with the goal of taking `:h2` and `:h3` elements and converting them to a tree of nested `:ul` and `:li`.

My starting point is a flat vector like:

```
[[:h2 {} "Foo"] [:h2 {} "Bar"] [:h3 {} "Child1"] [:h2 {} "Baz"]]
```

If I just map over these and replace `(first el)` with `[:li]`, I have a flat list. But I'd like to get something like:

`[[:li "Foo"] [:li "Bar"] [:ul [:li "Child1"]] [:li "Baz"]]`

If I call `(partition-by #(= :h2 (first %)) my-vec)`, I get something *almost* useful:

```
(([:h2 {} "Foo"] [:h2 {} "Bar"]) ([:h3 {} "Child1"]) ([:h2 {} "Baz"]))
```

The partition happens when the predicate `#(= :h2 (first %))` changes, (which is what the documentation says it does).

How can I get the behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that does the job, but is horribly inelegant, since it essentially mutates the last element in the `reduce` call when necessary:

```
(defn listify-element [element]
  "Replaces element type with :li."
  (vec (concat [:li (last element))]))

(defn listify-headings [headings-list]
  "Takes subitems (in :h2 :h3) and creates sub :uls out of the :h3 lists."
  (vec
   (concat
    [:ul]
    (map-indexed
     (fn [ind headings]
       (if (= 0 (mod ind 2))
         (map listify-element headings)
         (vec (concat [:ul] (map listify-element headings)))))
     (partition-by #(= :h2 (first %)) headings-list)))))

(defn nest-listified-headings [vector-list]
  "Nests sub-:uls inside their preceding :lis."
  (vec (concat [:ul]
          (reduce
           (fn [acc el] (if (= (first el) :ul)
                          (conj (pop (vec acc)) (conj (last acc) el))
                          (concat acc el)))
           vector-list))))
```

Produces:

```
(nest-listified-headings 
  (listify-headings [[:h2 "Foo"] [:h2 "Bar"] [:h3 "Baz"] [:h3 "Bat"]])

[:ul [:li "Foo"] 
     [:li "Bar" 
     [:ul 
       [:li "Baz"] 
       [:li "Bat"]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
(def data [
    [:h2 {} "Foo"]
    [:h2 {} "Bar"]
    [:h3 {} "Child1"]
    [:h2 {} "Baz"] ] )

(defn formatter [elem]
  (condp = (first elem)
    :h2           [:li (last elem)]
    :h3      [:ul [:li (last elem)]]
    ))

(newline) (println :data data)
(newline) (println :result (mapv formatter data))
```

with result

```
:data [[:h2 {} Foo] [:h2 {} Bar] [:h3 {} Child1] [:h2 {} Baz]]

:result [[:li Foo] [:li Bar] [:ul [:li Child1]] [:li Baz]]
```

### Update:

Rewrite like so to get all the `:h3` items in one `:ul`

```
(def data [
    [:h2 {} "Foo"]
    [:h3 {} "Child1"]
    [:h2 {} "Bar"]
    [:h3 {} "Child2"]
    [:h3 {} "Child3"]
    [:h2 {} "Baz"] ] )

(defn h2? [elem]
  (= :h2 (first elem)))

(defn ->li [elem]
  [:li (last elem)])

(defn fmt [data]
  (let [h2 (filter h2? data)
        h3 (filter #(not (h2? %)) data)
        result  (conj (mapv ->li h2)
                  (apply vector :ul (mapv ->li h3))) ]
        result ))

(newline) (println :data data)
(newline) (println :result (fmt data))
```

with result

```
:data [[:h2 {} Foo] [:h3 {} Child1] [:h2 {} Bar] [:h3 {} Child2] [:h3 {} Child3] [:h2 {} Baz]]

:result [[:li Foo] [:li Bar] [:li Baz] [:ul [:li Child1] [:li Child2] [:li Child3]]]
```

Comment: That works for the example, but as I understand it, will produce a `[:ul [:li` for every `:h3` that it sees.

Comment: Is that not the goal? How else would you do it?

Comment: Well, the blunt way to do it would be folding and checking the accumulated result every time the element being read is an `:h3`, but I was hoping there was something better.

Comment: Added an update to put all the `:h3` into the same `:ul`.  Gotta be precise with the question!  ;)

Comment: Sorry about that! I've had my head in markup land all day and didn't think about the context.